# Is this unchecked wrapper acceptable given the checked error will not be thrown in my program

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using an implementation of the Consumer Functional Interface which wraps the lambda and seemingly catches any checked exception and throws a Runtime unchecked exception instead. I really like this because it cleans up my lambdas and I am using it in a situation where the checked error in this case an InterruptedException will never be thrown anyway. Is this acceptable and if not why? The following is the Interface implementation:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T, E extends Throwable> {

void accept(T t) throws E;

static <T, E extends Throwable> Consumer<T> unchecked(ThrowingConsumer<T, E> c){
    return t -> {
        try{
            c.accept(t);
        } catch (Throwable e){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    };
}
```

}

The following is one example of its use. To give context it takes the EntrySet from a ConcurrentHashMap which contains for the key a user identifier and the value an Optional BlockingArrayQueue of type Packet used as a means of communication with each respective user. In this scenario I am sending every user a packet making them aware the relay sever will shutdown shortly to give them the opportunity to close cleanly before their threads are interrupted. Because the thread that spawned them was Main and has since finished execution and the Interrupt came from a ShutdownHook there is seemingly no way another interrupt could occur.

```
public class NetworkThread implements Runnable {

private SecureSocketManager secureSocketManager;
private final int tlsPort;
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>> channelMap;


public NetworkThread(SecureSocketManager secureSocketManager, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>> channelMap, int tlsPort) {
    this.secureSocketManager = secureSocketManager;
    this.tlsPort = tlsPort;
    this.channelMap = channelMap;
}

public void run() {

    ExecutorService clientThreads = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    // SETUP A SECURESOCKETMANAGER INSTANCE AND ESTABLISH A SERVER SOCKET ON DESIRED PORT

    try {
        SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = secureSocketManager.getSslServerSocket(tlsPort);

        // BEGIN RECEIVING NEW CONNECTION INSTANCES ON THAT PORT AND LOOP

        while (!interrupted()) {

            try {
                SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
                clientThreads.execute(new ClientThread(sslSocket, channelMap));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

//------------------------------RELEVANT CODE----------------------------------------------
    clientThreads.shutdown();

        // There should be no second interrupt so having this unchecked lambda wrapper is acceptable
       channelMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
               .forEach(ThrowingConsumer.unchecked(e -> e.getValue().get() // WRAPPER USE
               .put(new Packet(e.getKey(), "",Type.RELAY_SHUTDOWN, "", "" )))); 
       if(!clientThreads.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
           clientThreads.shutdownNow();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        clientThreads.shutdownNow();
    }


}

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this acceptable ...

Ask the person who has to accept it.  (Or decide for yourself!)

> ... and if not why?

It is unfortunate if you have to deal with checked exceptions in a stream.  But if you have to then you have to.

But I have a couple of problems with the way you are doing this:

1. You are catching all exceptions, not just checked exceptions.  If you were just catching `Exception` that would be bad.  But you are also catching `Error`.
2. You should *wrap* the original exception.  What you are currently doing is throwing it away.
3. Your wrapper exception needs a message.

---

I think that this addresses the above problems, as well as is possible:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T, E extends Exception> {

    void accept(T t) throws E;

    static <TT, EE extends Exception> Consumer<TT> unchecked(ThrowingConsumer<TT, EE> c){
        return t -> {
            try {
                c.accept(t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
                    throw e;
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected exception", e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Even this makes me feel a bit uneasy, because you are relying on generic type safety to ensure that you catch / wrap only a specific checked exception and it subclasses.  The problem is if you use unchecked conversions, etc, you can violate generic type safety.  In this case, it could result in the "wrong" checked exception being caught and wrapped.  Which is fine ... unless you try to unwrap it and cast it to the expected type.

Ideally you would use *runtime* type checking to ensure that you only wrap the *expected* exception.  But that requires you to pass the checked exception `Class` object to the `unchecked` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer as I improve with the language perhaps I shall return to these sacred texts and attempt to decipher some of them.